# Rearrange php Array structure

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, foreach

Is there any simple solution to convert `php` `mysql` result change array structure with `foreach` or any method ?

**Current result**

```
Array
(
    [1033] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1033
            [plugin] => kooyke
            [name] => kooyduration
            [value] => 13
        )

    [1029] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1029
            [plugin] => kooyke
            [name] => kooyendpoint
            [value] => http://localhost/public/data/
        )

    [1030] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1030
            [plugin] => kooyke
            [name] => kooylogin
            [value] => ryrtrtr68fds876fdsf876fsd87fd
        )
)
```

**Expecting result**

```
Array
(
    [kooyduration] => 13
    [kooyendpoint] => http://localhost/public/data/
    [kooylogin] => ryrtrtr68fds876fdsf876fsd87fd
)
```

the code trying to convert

```
foreach($result as $value){
  $expresult[] = $value['value'];
}
print_r($expresult);
```

Comment: why two brackets after Array ??

Comment: The rules by which you transformed that structure seem totally arbitrary. Maybe you could describe them to us? Edit: more specifically, why is the `id` 1033?

Comment: @Khushboo updated the expecting result code

Comment: @Sergiu Paraschiv you are right, just deleted that part

Comment: Then it's pretty clear. How is a simple `foreach` not working? What have you tried? The solution is five lines long...

Comment: @Sergiu Paraschiv
 I have updated my code in question

Comment: What you need is `$expresult[$value['name']] = $value['value'];`

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv when try like that result coming as error `Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use like `$value['value']`, should be `$value->value` because of object. And push new array your `name` index. Try following:

```
$expresult = array();

foreach($result as $value)
{
  $expresult[$value->name] = $value->value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bellow code blocks may help you.

```
$i = 0;
$last_arr = array();
$new_arr = array();
foreach($my_array as $key=>$val)
{
   $new_arr[$val->name] = $val->value;
}
array_push($last_arr,$new_arr);
```